# Can I not use QM-AM inequality to solve this?

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

I was doing my inequality homework and I encountered the following problem:

> Show that $\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\ge(a+b+c)\sqrt2.$$

I came up a prove using QM-AM inequality, as follows (you can also try to prove with QM-AM inequality for exercise).

> [image]

But my problem is, can we not use the QM-AM inequality?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to solve it without AM-QM?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, the QM-AM proof is just for reference.

Comment: The two answers currently given below use essentially the same inequalities, but do not _call_ them AM-QM. Is that good enough? Because "Do not use AM-QM" is a bit vague of a requirement.

Comment: @Arthur In my worldview, QM/AM does not exist, only AM/GM.

Comment: Consider a square whose one side has length $a+b+c$ and the other $b+c+a$ :).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : So what's your position on the [QM-AM-GM-HM](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/gwan01200422828.pdf) (or the same set of initials in reverse order) inequalities?

Comment: @EricTowers Uh... it's just that the notion of quadratic mean is quite alien to my computationally geared mind. AM, GM, those are central. HM is basically a rehashed AM. But QM is hardly ever used in the numerical problems I sometimes solve. (Don't forget the _AGM_.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the hint given in the comments, consider the following diagram:

[image]

The inequality's LHS is the sum of lengths of diagonals that have been drawn in the diagram. However, this being a path from corner to opposite corner, it must be at least as long as a straight line, which has length equal to the RHS. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a purely visual proof based on Michal Adamaszek's comment:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By CS:

$\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^2=2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2+2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\geq 2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2+2\sum\limits_{cyc}(ac+ab)=2(a+b+c)^2$

Answer (score 3):

By using Hölder’s Inequality,
$$ \bigl(a^2+b^2\bigr)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\bigl(1+1\bigr)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\ge a+b \\ \sqrt{a^2+b^2\mathstrut} \ge \dfrac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Similarly for others, and end it yourself

Comment: This is essentially the same proof.

Comment: Sorry, there is a better answer. So I accepted it.